# Child Terms do not display in modern terms form

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, managed-metadata, modern-experience, term-store

I have a set of terms:

- Marketing
- ->Series (NOT available for tagging)
- -> -> Series A
- -> -> Series B
- -> -> etc...

In my Sharepoint List I have created a column using that Managed Metadata, using Series as the root tag.
When I go to tag a document and pull up the tags list, all that is show is the Series tag, which of course is disabled for tagging. None of its children show up:

[image: Modern Metadata List]

However, When I "Return to classic" the tags are loaded as I expected:

[image: Classic Metadata List]

Am I missing something in configuration settings, or is this a Sharepoint bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by enabling tagging on the parent tag. It still will not be available to tag your list item, so it suited my purpose just fine.